# How can I see the numbers of rows a query affects when deleting

Tags: postgresql

I want to see how many rows my delete query effects so I know its correct.

Is this possible using pgadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a transaction, delete and then rollback;

In psql :

```
test1=> begin;
BEGIN
test1=> delete from test1 where test1_id = 1;
DELETE 2
test1=> rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

In pgAdmin (in the "History" tab on the "Output pane"):

```
-- Executing query:
begin;
Query returned successfully with no result in 16 ms.

-- Executing query:
delete from test1 where test1_id = 1;
Query returned successfully: 2 rows affected, 16 ms execution time.

-- Executing query:
rollback;
Query returned successfully with no result in 16 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to automatically do this but you can always do a select then a delete.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE delete_me=true;

DELETE FROM foo WHERE delete_me=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew said, when doing interactive administration, you can just replace `DELETE` by `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

If you want to this information in a *program* of yours (*after* executing the DELETE), many programming languages provide a construct for this. For example, in PHP it's [pg_affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php) and in .NET it's the return value of [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-delete.html) and fetch the result like you would fetch a SELECT-result:

```
DELETE FROM test1 WHERE test1_id = 1 RETURNING id;
```

This works as of version 8.2